# Updating object within function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Anybody suggest why the button doesn't work here? I must have a syntax error but the console is showing no errors and the JS is valid. http://jsfiddle.net/FZ6K6/20/

```
self.msg = function () {
    self.msgbox = { 
        status: "information", 
        message: "Enter some info"
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a constructor function to `applyBindings()`.
Since the function itself has no useful properties, nothing happens.

You probably want to pass an instance of that function using `new`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues here, including the lack of an instance of your View Model.
Check out the notes I posted on this updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/FZ6K6/22/

```
ko.applyBindings(new FormViewModel(),document.getElementById('domElementToBind'));
```

Not only are we 'new-ing' up an instance of FormViewModel, but we're also specifically assigning a DOM element to apply the bindings to...which is good practice.